# Xcode Error: "Buildfile: build.xml does not exist! Build failed"

Tags: java, xcode, macos, ant

I am trying to use Xcode 3.2 for java tool development. My project has no problem building and shows it built the file build.xml fine and also shows up in file folder fine. When I try to run the .java file, I get the error: "Buildfile: build.xml does not exist! Build failed". Running "ant -find build.xml" in Terminal produces "not found". I believe the problem is that I need to point to my own build.xml location, but I have no idea how to change which directory it looks for this file. Any help is greatly appreciated. -nick

Mac OS 10.6, Xcode 3.2.1
- method to create app: Organizer>New from template>Java Tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to build fine now. Turns out it was building fine, I was just running the .java file and not the entire built application. but now I know how to build via Terminal.

Comment: In Xcode, You have to have the project selected when building, if you use the .java file alone it will fail.

Answer (score 1):

The [Ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#commandline) says this:

> When no arguments are specified, Ant looks for a `build.xml` file in the current directory and, if found, uses that file as the build file and runs the target specified in the default attribute of the `<project>` tag. To make Ant use a build file other than `build.xml`, use the command-line option `-buildfile file`, where `file` is the name of the build file you want to use.

So the answer your question is that you either need to change directory to the directory containing the `build.xml` file, or you need to add a `-buildfile file` option, where `file` is the *pathname* for the build file.

Comment: thanks for the response, I got it to build fine now. Turns out it was building fine, I was just running the .java file and not the entire built application. but now I know how to build via Terminal, thanks again! -nick